# Wordpress Blur / Pixelated Images on first run

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress website for a client.
The client reported a problem that the website home page shows blur images on first load. After a refresh or second run the images load fine.

url: slmp.com.pk

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Disable Adaptive images in the theme control panel.

Answer (score 0):

On the first load the image is coming from this:

```
<img src="https://www.slmp.com.pk/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Screenshot_16-uai-258x26.png" alt="logo" width="258" height="26" class="img-responsive adaptive-async adaptive-fetching" data-uniqueid="93-141064" data-guid="https://www.slmp.com.pk/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Screenshot_16.png" data-path="2016/12/Screenshot_16.png" data-width="999" data-height="100" data-singlew="null" data-singleh="null" data-crop="" data-fixed="height">
```

and second load is coming from this

```
<img src="https://www.slmp.com.pk/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Screenshot_16.png" alt="logo" width="999" height="100" class="img-responsive">
```

if you change the image src on the first load to `https://www.slmp.com.pk/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Screenshot_16.png` it will load fine.

Comment: The wordpress website is built with VisualComposer. Who decides which picture to load? How to fix this on WordPress Portal?

Comment: Is the logo added from visual composer? If yes try to change the image src.

Comment: This would be an answer for a developer so that he can quickly and temporarily check the difference but the answer is disabling adaptive images and clearing cache.

Answer (score 0):

In the div with a class of `background-wrapper` there is another div with a background image.

Whatever calls that background image should be something like `get_post_thumbnail( $post_id )`

Add a second parameter of `full` to the call like this `get_post_thumbnail( $post_id, 'full' )` to ensure that the full sized image is always pulled in.

Comment: Is there any way to fix this from WordPress Portal?

Comment: Not without seeing more details, or the code to learn why the thumbnail is pulled on first load only.